# list of global variables that are not functions

Tags: javascript

I want to get a list of all global variables. On another answer, I found this:

```
Object.keys( window );
```

The problem is that it also lists function names that defined globally. Is there a way to get just the ones that aren't functions?

I tried this:

```
function Test() {

    var f = Object.keys(window);

    for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {

        if (typeof (f[i]) !== 'function') {

            console.log(f[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's still showing functions.
Thanks.

Comment: Filter them out? There's no single function for getting all property names for non-callable properties if you mean that.

Comment: [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `for..in` on window, and check each item to make sure it's not a function:

```
var globalVars = [];
for (var name in window) {
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(name) && typeof window[name] != "function") {
        globalVars.push(name);
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HxeEU/)

Comment: that routine finds 81 object on this page, mine finds 88, just in case you need the extra 7...

Comment: those 7 are ("Infinity", "JSON", "Math", "NaN", "event", "globals", and "undefined")... oops, make that 6 ;)

Comment: `window` doesn't have a `hasOwnProperty` method in some versions of IE. You can use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, name)` in your code to overcome this

Answer (score 2):

In your code f[i] is the key, not the value assigned to the key. So...

You're checking that the key's typeof is not a 'function', which it's not, it's always 'string'.

What you want for your test is:

```
if (typeof(window[f[i]]) !== 'function')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but this line is wrong:

> ```
> if (typeof (f[i]) !== 'function') {
> ```

Since `f` is an array of property names, an item `f[i]` will always be a string. To check wether the respective `window` property is a function, use

```
if (typeof window[f[i]] !== 'function') {
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a comprehensive listing:

```
var globals=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(__proto__)
  .concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)).filter(function(a){
    return !String(this[a]).match(/^function/) && typeof this[a] !== "function";
}).sort().filter(function(a,b,c){return c.lastIndexOf(a)===b; });

alert(globals);
```

edit: added unique filter to result set...
edit: remove duplicate gathering

Comment: What do you expect in `Object.keys(window)` that is neither an own property of `window` nor of its prototype?

Comment: i thought that i got a different count when i added .keys(), i was wondering why, but i must have been looking at something wrong, good catch and thanks!